# Android icon wrong in App Management app, but correct in Launcher

Tags: android

I have a simple Android app (built with Mono for Android), which has a problem with it's icon.

- The icon is correct in Launcher and in Task Switcher, but
- In Manage Apps and in Task Manager it's displayed a generic Android icon

I've checked the various density resources and the manifest and they all look correct.

(I'm seeing this on a Galaxy S phone and on a Nexus 7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you set the `icon` property for your activities within `AndroidManifest.xml`, but did not set it for the application.

Answer (score 4):

It occurs to me, that the app icon is somehow being cached in the app manager, so that deinstalling and reinstalling the app does not always change the icon properly. Rebooting the device could help.
Also i found [this post](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename) very useful: adding application ids in gradle usually solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open "AndroidMenifest.xml" in the Package Explorer and click on the "Application" **tab** at the bottom. Look at the "icon" field and enter the location for your icon ( Ex: `@drawable/iconimage`). Next, go into the "AndroidManifest.xml" **tab** and look for `android:icon=`, adding the location to that as well (Ex: `android:icon="@drawable/iconimage`)

Make sure you have the same icon name in both locations!

Answer (score -1):

Oleg and Collin are both right but for completeness - in a Mono app the icon can be set with attributes on the Application object (if you have one):

```
[Application(Label = "MyAppName", Icon = "@drawable/icon")] 
class MyApp: Application
{ ...
```